# Given a class type how do I create an instance in Python?

Tags: python, oop

Let's say I have this :

```
class whatever(object):
   def __init__(self):
      pass
```

and this function:

```
def create_object(type_name):
   # create an object of type_name
```

I'd like to be able to call the `create_object` like this:

```
inst = create_object(whatever)
```

and get back an instance of `whatever`. I think this should be doable without using `eval`, I'd like to know how to do this. Please notice that I'm **NOT** using a string as a parameter for `create_object`.

Comment: What Python tutorial are you reading, @Geo?  Your question indicates that the tutorial is missing important information.  Which one did you read?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious way:

```
def create_object(type_name):
    return type_name()
```

Comment: Classes are just normal first-class objects in Python, sharing the same namespace as any other variables.

Answer (score 5):

```
def create_object(typeobject):
  return typeobject()
```

As you so explicitly say that the arg to `create_object` is NOT meant to be a string, I assume it's meant to be the type object itself, just like in the `create_object(whatever)` example you give, in which `whatever` is indeed the type itself.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, what you want is:

```
def create_object(type_name, *args):
    # create an object of type_name
    return type_name(*args)

inst = create_object(whatever)
```

I don't really know *why* you want to do this, but would be interesting to hear from you what are your reasons to need such a construct.

Comment: `eval` and its uglier, meanier brother, `exec` are rarely needed, if at all. `eval` is usefull to evaluate user input, as long as you take measures to not use the appliaction `globals` and `locals`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def create_object(type_name):
   return type_name()
```

you can of course skip the function altogether and create the instance of `whatever` like this:

```
inst = whatever()
```